# How can I add products that will be part of assortment pack?

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

Struggling with how to set up products for the following scenario.  Would appreciate any insight or assistance.

**Products**

We sell beverage products that are similar size but different flavors.

- 12 SKUs in total
- Each SKU is sold as a 6-pack
- Each SKU should display on the page as a separate product (ex. Vanilla, Cherry, etc.)

**Buying Process**

The customer must buy in multiples of two '6-packs' to complete the order.  This means the minimum order must contain either of the following:

1. two '6-packs' of one SKU (ex. two '6-packs' of Vanilla) **OR**
2. one '6-pack' each of 2 specific SKUs (ex. one '6-pack' Orange plus one '6-pack' Grape)

Comment: One question you have shop already created  in magento ?? Or pls to build site in magento

Comment: @KeyulShah working on creating magento site at the moment but wanted to lay out the product details before I get to deep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple options for you depending on how you want to set it up.

You could simply create all separate skus, and set the minimum qty allowed in cart to 2 in
System> Configuration >Inventory.
That assumes all products on your site fit this criteria.

Another would be to create one sku and set the item to have custom options (which can add to the sku for each option. ex. sku could be soda and each option would be soda-cherry, soda-grape etc.) Then you would set that product to have a minimum order quantity of 2 in it's inventory tab, and still be giving options.

Comment: In this first option we would be able to show all products and their nutritionals as stand alone. Also, it would allow us to keep inventory.

In the second option would we lose the inventory capability as well as having specific nutrition information for each product?